# how to do "update table field=field+1 where id =5" in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to increment the value in database on each call.

ie how to do "update table field=field+1  where id =5" in ruby on rails

how to do "update table field=field+1  where id =5" in ruby on rails

Comment: @training_session.trainingSessions = @training_session.trainingSessions+1

Comment: hello...it worked successfully

Comment: Excellent! :) Don't forget to add that as an answer, so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@training_session.trainingSessions = @training_session.trainingSessions+1`

Answer (score 3):

There's a special method for this in Rails, called `increment_counter(counter_name, id)`. For example, if a forum has many topics and there's a topics_count field on the Forum model (which there should be, for caching/performace reasons):

```
Forum.increment_counter(:topics_count, 1)
```